# Animate/Shrink NavBar on scroll using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I've searched a whole heap for this but cant seem to find a working solution. Basically I've got my NavBar perfectly how I want it. I now want to shrink the NavBar when my page scrolls down to make it more slim using a nice smooth transition (animation).

This is my HTML markup for my current NavBar:

```
<header>


      <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
          <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="animated bounceIn" src="img/logo-light.png" alt="I Web You &#8211; Perth Website Branding"></a>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </nav>


    </header>
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this? I've done a lot of searching but most solutions were for Bootstrap 3.

Cheers

Comment: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/pjvmD

Comment: This answer works in v4 https://stackoverflow.com/a/24765232/253096

Comment: @TimoSolo -- that answer doesn't seem to work in Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 24):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

Bootstrap 5 still has the `sticky-top` class that can be used to create a static-to-fixed Navbar effect when the page is scrolled.

[Bootstrap 5 stick navbar after scrolling (simply sticky-top)](https://codeply.com/p/Gq9DKl9zNY)

Another option is to use a JavaScript IntersectionObserver. This method watches for a "trigger" element. Once the trigger element is visible in the viewport, a CSS class is added to the Navbar. This "stuck" CSS class can contain whatever CSS is needed to change the Navbar style and position.

[Bootstrap 5 stick navbar after scrolling (animate with IntersectionObserver)](https://codeply.com/p/wHQ6QdMkrV)

---

**Bootstrap 4 (Updated 2018)**

Most of the shrink on scroll Navbar implementations for Bootstrap 3.x are done using the Affix component to change the style of the navbar at a specific scroll position.

**However, Affix [has been dropped](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#components) from Bootstrap 4**..

> "Dropped the Affix jQuery plugin. We recommend using a position: sticky
> polyfill instead. See the HTML5 Please entry for details and specific
> polyfill recommendations."

To create a similar Navbar effect in Bootstrap 4, you can use `position: sticky` (not supported in all browsers) by adding the **`sticky-top`** class to the Navbar. This works to "*stick*" the Navbar when it reaches the top, **but *doesn't* trigger an event to indicate when the it's "*stuck*". Therefore, JS is needed to change the Navbar style when it's "*stuck*".**

---

One JS method supported in modern browsers is `IntersectionObserver`. Use it to "watch" when a hidden trigger element above the Navbar reaches the viewport (when `stuck` is applied to the `html` element).

```
.stuck .sticky-top {
    background-color: #222;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

[Sticky Top Navbar - IntersectionObserver Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/H7ZKuxKTKm)

---

You could also jQuery plugin such as [ScrollPos-Styler](https://github.com/acch/scrollpos-styler), or write your own jQuery to control the navbar styles on scroll...

**How it works:**

A fixed-top Navbar with `data-toggle="affix"`:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top navbar-expand-sm py-3" data-toggle="affix">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
      <a class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">☰</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">..</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery to watch scroll position and conditionally toggle the `.affix` class:

```
var toggleAffix = function(affixElement, scrollElement, wrapper) {
    var height = affixElement.outerHeight(),
        top = wrapper.offset().top;
    
    if (scrollElement.scrollTop() >= top){
        wrapper.height(height);
        affixElement.addClass("affix");
    }
    else {
        affixElement.removeClass("affix");
        wrapper.height('auto');
    }
};
  
/* use toggleAffix on any data-toggle="affix" elements */
$('[data-toggle="affix"]').each(function() {
    var ele = $(this),
        wrapper = $('<div></div>');
    
    ele.before(wrapper);
    $(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
        toggleAffix(ele, $(this), wrapper);
    });
    
    // init
    toggleAffix(ele, $(window), wrapper);
});
```

CSS to manipulate the affix style (padding/height, color, etc..):

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
    padding-top:56px; /*height of fixed navbar*/
}

.navbar { 
  -webkit-transition:padding 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition:padding 0.2s ease; 
  -o-transition:padding 0.2s ease;        
  transition:padding 0.2s ease;  
}

.affix {
  padding-top: 0.2em !important;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em !important;
  -webkit-transition:padding 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition:padding 0.2s linear;  
  -o-transition:padding 0.2s linear;         
  transition:padding 0.2s linear;  
}

section {
    min-height:calc(100% - 70px);
}
```

---

Note: As of **Bootstrap 4.0.0**, the Navbar has changed slightly as `navbar-toggleable-*` has change to `navbar-expand-`

[Sticky Top Navbar - jQuery Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/EfianX3H0U)

---

Finally, you can use a simple jQuery $(window).scroll() function if you know the exact position of when the Navbar needs to stick...

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  /* affix after scrolling 100px */
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('.navbar').addClass('affix');
  } else {
    $('.navbar').removeClass('affix');
  }
});
```

https://codeply.com/go/62Roy6RDOa

---

**More Bootstrap 4 change Navbar style on scroll examples**:
[simply sticky after scroll](https://www.codeply.com/go/oY2CyNiA7A) (4.0.0)
[shrink height](https://www.codeply.com/go/EfianX3H0U) (4.0.0)
[shrink height](http://www.codeply.com/go/P56jeGN0TH) (alpha-6)
[transparent over background](https://www.codeply.com/go/5BkmKx0qcH/bootstrap-4-affix-navbar-transparent)
[change color after scroll](https://www.codeply.com/go/6j1umrmGxi/bootstrap-4-affix-navbar-affix-color)
[change navbar bg color with scrollspy sections](https://www.codeply.com/go/enTfLemKdl)

Related questions:
[Fixing navbar to top on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464026/fixing-navbar-to-top-on-scroll)
[Affix is not working in Bootstrap 4 (alpha)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349879/affix-is-not-working-in-bootstrap-4-alpha/39147077)

Comment: Your links (at least for Bootstrap 5) don't open for me. They time out. Do you think you could put the code in snippets instead? That way everyone can view the examples.

Answer (score 5):

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

```css
nav.navbar.shrink {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #111;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #dadada;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    transition: all 1.5s ease;

}
nav.navbar.shrink .navbar-brand  img{
  height: 50px;
  width: 120px;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
nav.navbar.shrink a {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  padding-top: 10px !important;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
nav.navbar.shrink .navbar-toggler {
  margin: 8px 15px 8px 0;
  padding: 4px 5px;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

.header{

 
 height:100px;
}

.navbar-brand{

 padding-left:30px;
 padding-top:30px;
 padding-bottom:30px;

}

.collapse{

 padding-right:30px;
}

.logo{


 width: 170px;
 height: 58px;
}


.hero-container p{
  color:black;
  text-align: center;
  height:auto;
}

.image-container{
 text-align:center;
}

.banner{

 background-image: url(../images/banner.jpg); 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 padding-top: 70px;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-right:30px;
 padding-bottom: 78px;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 }

.banner .row h4,p{

   color: white;
}

.client{

 height: 635px;
 margin-top:74px;
 padding-right:10px;
 padding-left:10px;
}

.btn-primary{

 
 background: transparent;
 width:170px;
 border: 1px solid white;
 color:white;
}


form{
    padding-top:56px;
    padding-bottom:56px;
 padding-left: 30px;
    height:auto;
 }

form,h2,label{
 color:white;
}

.above{
 margin-bottom:34px;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 padding-right: 30px;
}

.below{

 width:100%;
 height:auto;
    padding-right: 30px;

}

.heading{
 color: black;
 margin-top: 62px;
}

.lead{
color:black;
}

.form_banner{
    
 background-image: url(../images/form_banner.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 
    width: 100%;
    
}

.contact{
 background-image: url(../images/contact.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 margin-top:50px;
 height:auto;
 width:100%;
 padding-left: 313px;
 padding-right:313px;
 padding-top: 64px;
 padding-bottom:64px;
 text-align: center;
}

.contact, h5{

 color:white;
}

hr{
 display: block;
    margin-top: 0.1em;
    margin-bottom: 0.1em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1px;
}

.footer_img{

 padding-left: 30px;
 width:170px;
 height:63px;
}

.footer{
 margin-bottom: 41px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  
  
</head>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="header container">
<div class="row">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HeRo</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Company<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Capabilities</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Customers</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#">Innovation</a>
          </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
         
         
        </ul>
        
      </div>
    </nav>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    
<div class="hero-container container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    
    <p>Commerce</p>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
  
            <p>Interactive</p>
            <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p></div>
    <div class="col">
    

            <p>Analytics</p>
            <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p></div>
    <div class="col">
    
            <p>Integration</p>
            <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p></div>
    <div class="col">
    
            <p>Cloud & Management Services</p>
            <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p></div>
</div>
</div>
    
<div class="banner container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Dedicated, Experience, Innovative</h4>
        <p>For over a decade our experienced team has been delivering Digital Commerce solutions that change the way consumers research, interact and purchase. As mobility and pervasive connectivity continue to transform buying habits, we are focused on helping businesses discover and maximise new opportunities – be it direct to consumers, via resellers, or by other innovative models.</p>

          <p>Our expertise is centred on the Digital Commerce solution that excels in delivering best-in-class Scalability and User Experience. From our global headquarters in India, we have expanded to empower Clients across four continents, with offices located in Singapore, USA, Australia and the UK.</p>
        <h4>BUSINESS</h4>
        <p>Our approach is to listen to you as the experts in your market. We look to complement your insight with a project team capable of understanding your business and delivering better digital experience. Our in-country Advisors will help assess your requirements and collaboratively design a service that meets your strategic goals.</p>

        <h4>TECHNOLOGY</h4>
        <p>With a specialised team of Creative Designers, Developers, Engineers and Architects we have substantial experience across many leading enterprise and open source platforms. Beyond our core expertise in Digital Commerce, we also offer Mobility, Integration, Digital Analytics, Development and other custom Web and applications development services.</p>
    </div>
</div>



 <!-- FOOTER -->
<div class="footer container">
     
  <div class="clearfix">
    <span class="float-left"><a href="#"><img class="footer_img" src="images/ibm_logo.png"></a></span>
    <span class="float-right">&copy; AbcXyZ Inc and Affiliates.All Rights Reserved</span>
 </div>

</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  
</body>
</html>
```

Use this code.It's simple and easy. I hope you would get a understanding. I have made a class shrink which it would add to the navbar once it crosses 50 pixels. And rest is all css, which I have put in the Shrink class.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the above answers looked long and complicated, surely (I thought) there must be a really sleek way to do this now in Bootstrap 4.1 - it's 2018!
Well yeh - nah....There are some interesting answers around the net, if you have a look at some of the templates at [startbootstrap.com](https://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/all/) for example.

I didn't see anything vastly different from those above...

Add or remove a class on scroll/ page load...

```
    var o = function() {
      var mn = $("#mainNav");
      mn.offset().top > 100 ? mn.addClass("navbar-shrink") : mn.removeClass("navbar-shrink");
    };
    o(), $(window).scroll(o);
```

Then style based on that appended class...

```
 #mainNav {
       background-color: #0f6f56;
       transition: all 1s ease;
    }

    #mainNav.navbar-shrink {
      background-color: pink;
    }
```