# Show Navbar only when scrolling to top on mobile (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, sticky

I want to show the navbar on mobile only if the user scrolls to the top of the page.

At the moment it's stuck on the top everytime the user scrolls down or up.
I'm using the code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42250478/1788961
Here's the example: https://www.codeply.com/go/H7ZKuxKTKm

My JS code:

```
new IntersectionObserver(function(e,o){
        if (e[0].intersectionRatio > 0){
            document.documentElement.removeAttribute('class');
        } else {
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('class','stuck');
        };
    }).observe(document.querySelector('.trigger'));
```

Edit: to clarify what I want:

I don't want the navbar on mobile to be sticky. It should scroll away with the rest of the site. But if I'm on the bottom of the page and I scroll to the top, the navbar should appear on the top and stay there as long as I scroll to the top.

Comment: So what you issuse??

Comment: I don’t know how to add the stuck class only if i scroll to the top on mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a CSS media query only apply `position:sticky` on mobile (ie; <768px)...

```
.sticky-top {
    position: static;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    .sticky-top {
        transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
        position: sticky;
    }

    .stuck .sticky-top {
        background-color: #222 !important;
        padding-top: 3px !important;
        padding-bottom: 3px !important;
    }
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/1b80jD3Tpg

If you want the opposite effect (non-sticky navbar on mobile) just reverse the media query to `min-width` instead of max-width...

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .sticky-top {
        transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
        position: sticky;
    }

    .stuck .sticky-top {
        background-color: #222 !important;
        padding-top: 3px !important;
        padding-bottom: 3px !important;
    }
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/4RtpB24k23

Comment: Yes, but then the navbar doesn't show if I scroll to the top

Comment: Don't know what you mean. It doesn't show at the top when?

Comment: I want to show the navbar on mobile only if I scroll to the top.

Comment: And that's what it's doing. I think you need to clarify the question. Do you *not* want to show the navbar at all on non-mobile? The expected behavior isn't clear.

Comment: I don't want the navbar on mobile to be sticky. It should scroll away with the rest of the site. But if I'm on the bottom of the page and I scroll to the top, the navbar should appear on the top and stay there as long as I scroll to the top.

Comment: That sounds like you don't want it to be sticky. "sticky" means it appears on the top as you scroll. If it disappears as you scroll away then it 's not sticky.

Comment: ah ok, that's my fault. sorry to be not clear about that

Answer (score 0):

The class "sticky-top" makes the navbar stick to the top of the page even if the user scrolls. Taking it off fixes your issue.

Example here: https://www.codeply.com/go/wWKGkjYdGy

Comment: but I don't want it off, I need it to appear only if I scroll to the top

Comment: I don't understand. The navbar is visible when you scroll to the top. Do you mean you want it visible if the user's at the bottom and starts scrolling up?

Comment: this jsfiddle does something very similar http://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/

Comment: did that jsfiddle help?