# How to change navbar background color when scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I scroll the page more than the height of navbar, I want to change navbar background color.

To achieve this, I used below logic but problem is before scrolling the navbar background color is changed, and text color stays same as before.

What is my mistake here?

Sample code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="assets/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Karvy InnoTech</title>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top scrolled">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-lg-auto">

                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#explore">Explore</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#adventure">Adventure</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#blog">Blog</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid heigh100p banner" id="home">
        <div class="container h100">
            <div class="contentBox h100">
                <div>
                    <h1>Fluid jumbotron</h1>
                    <p>This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="sec1" id="explore">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-8">
                    <div class="headerText text-center">
                        <h2>Explotre the world please</h2>
                        <p>This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                            parent.This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                            parent.This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                            parent.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="placebox">
                        <div class="imgBox">
                            <img src="assets/home_beach.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3>Country name<br><span>Place Name</span></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="placebox">
                        <div class="imgBox">
                            <img src="assets/home_beach.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3>Country name<br><span>Place Name</span></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="placebox">
                        <div class="imgBox">
                            <img src="assets/home_beach.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h3>Country name<br><span>Place Name</span></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="sec2" id="adventure">
        <div class="container h100">
            <div class="contentBox h100">
                <div>
                    <h1>Adventure is everywhere</h1>
                    <p>This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                        parent.This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                        parent.This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                        parent.This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                        parent.This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                        parent.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btnD1">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="blogpost" id="blog">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-8">
                    <div class="headerText">
                        <h2>This is our latest blog</h2>
                        <p>This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                            parent.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="blogPost">
                        <div class="imgBox">
                            <img src="assets/home_beach.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>This is blog1</h1>
                            <p>This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                                parent.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="blogPost">
                        <div class="imgBox">
                            <img src="assets/home_beach.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>This is blog1</h1>
                            <p>This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                                parent.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="blogPost">
                        <div class="imgBox">
                            <img src="assets/home_beach.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>This is blog1</h1>
                            <p>This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                                parent.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="blogPost">
                        <div class="imgBox">
                            <img src="assets/home_beach.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>This is blog1</h1>
                            <p>This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                                parent.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="contact" id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="headerText text-center">
                        <h2>This is our contact page</h2>
                        <p>This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its
                            parent.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class=" offset-sm-2 col-sm-8">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1"
                                aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone
                                else.</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"
                                placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <ul class="sco">
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).scroll(function () {
            $('.navbar').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $('.navbar').height());
        })

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Please find running example code: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/rama-krishna-the-selector/pen/GemNrB?editors=1010)

Comment: I see this working on you CodePen, you scroll navbar goes black?
What is not working exactly?

Comment: it works well for me. Not sure what's not working correctly?!

Comment: initially navbar should not be black when i scroll then only it should be blabk

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237406/animate-shrink-navbar-on-scroll-using-bootstrap-4/42250478?r=SearchResults&s=1|84.7690#42250478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `scrolled` class is being applied at the start.

Simply add `$(".navbar").removeClass('scrolled');` in your script so that it won't start with a black background. ^^

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if you've got it working! ^^