# How can I change the Bootstrap 4 navbar button icon color?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap website where the hamburger toggler is added when the screen size is less than 992px. The code is like so:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" 
        type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
        aria-expanded="false" 
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
</button>
```

Is there any possibility to change the color of the hamburger toggler button?

Comment: Code does not run as is in bootply

Comment: Not really an answer, but you can play around with the navbar-toggler-icon at https://www.advertentiekracht.nl/togglerIcon.html
There bootstraps toggler-icon is used as an external style element instead of referring to the bootstrap style-sheet. It is also explained how to manage that.

Answer (score 334, accepted):

The `navbar-toggler-icon` (hamburger) in Bootstrap 4 uses an SVG `background-image`. There are 2 "versions" of the toggler icon image. One for a light navbar, and one for a dark navbar...

- Use `navbar-dark` for a light/white toggler on darker backgrounds
- Use `navbar-light` for a dark/gray toggler on lighter backgrounds

---

```
// this is a black icon with 50% opacity
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;..");
}
// this is a white icon with 50% opacity
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;..");
}
```

Therefore, if you want to change the color of the toggler image to something else, you can customize the icon. For example, here I set the RGB value to pink (255,102,203). Notice the `stroke='rgba(255,102,203, 0.5)'` value in the SVG data:

```
.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,102,203, 0.5)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.custom-toggler.navbar-toggler {
  border-color: rgb(255,102,203);
}
```

**Demo** http://www.codeply.com/go/4FdZGlPMNV

OFC, another option to just use an icon from another library ie: Font Awesome, etc..

---

**Update Bootstrap 4.0.0:**

As of Bootstrap 4 Beta, `navbar-inverse` is now `navbar-dark` to use on navbars with darker background colors to produce lighter link and toggler colors.

---

[How to change Bootstrap 4 Navbar colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18530995/171456)

Comment: In Bootstrap  4 beta 1 there is no `.navbar-inverse` class. you can choose from two classes: `.navbar-light` or `.navbar-dark`.

Comment: I copied the SVG url from Chrome to edit it and the stroke path bit was `stroke='rgba%280, 0, 0, 0.5%29'` which I read as `rgba(280, 0, 0, 0.5)` (yes I'm an idiot; 280 > 255) and when I deleted and replaced the `280` it didn't work and it took me a few minutes to realise the %28 was a thing, i.e. url encoded opening parenthesis.

Answer (score 80):

Use a [font-awesome icon](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started) as the default icon of your navbar.

```html
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon">   
    <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color:#fff; font-size:28px;"></i>
</span>
```

Or try this on old font-awesome versions:

```
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon">   
    <i class="fa fa-navicon" style="color:#fff; font-size:28px;"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: For fontawesome 5 use bars. https://fontawesome.com/icons/bars?style=solid

Comment: Do I even need the class="navbar-toggler-icon"?

Answer (score 14):

If you downloaded bootstrap, go to `bootstrap-4.4.1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`

1. find the `.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon` or the `.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler-icon` selector
2. select the `background-image` attribute and its value. The snippet looks like this:

   ```
   .navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
   }
   ```
3. copy the snippet and paste it in your custom CSS
4. change the `stroke='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'` value to your preferred rgba value

Answer (score 12):

Easiest way is replace this default bootstrap code:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

by this :

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="" role="button" ><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#e6e6ff"></i></span>
</button>
```

And don't forget to add this code also to your file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 11):

You can create the toggler button with css only in a very easy way, there is no need to use any fonts in SVG or ... foramt.

**Your Button:**

```
<button 
     class="navbar-toggler collapsed" 
    data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" 
    data-toggle="collapse">
        <span class="line"></span> 
        <span class="line"></span> 
        <span class="line"></span>
</button>
```

**Your Button Style:**

```
.navbar-toggler{
width: 47px;
height: 34px;
background-color: #7eb444;
 }
```

**Your horizontal line Style:**

```
.navbar-toggler .line{
width: 100%;
float: left;
height: 2px;
background-color: #fff;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

**Demo**

```css
.navbar-toggler{
    width: 47px;
    height: 34px;
    background-color: #7eb444;
    border:none;
}
.navbar-toggler .line{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" >
        <span class="line"></span> 
        <span class="line"></span> 
        <span class="line" style="margin-bottom: 0;"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 10):

just insert class `navbar-dark` or `navbar-light` in the nav element:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md">
    <button class="navbar-toggler">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</nav>
```

Comment: So when you need a light icon you use the navbar-dark value.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, just delete this span from your code: `<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>` , then paste this font awesome icon that called bars: `<i class="fas fa-bars"></i>`, add a class to this icon, then put any color you want.

Then, the second step is to hide this icon from the devices that have width more than `992px` (desktops width), due to this icon will appear in your interface at any device if you won't add this `@media` in your css code:

```
 /* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
    /* the class you gave of the bars icon ↑ */
    .iconClass{
        display: none;
    }
    /* the bootstrap toogler button class */
    .navbar-toggler{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

It worked for me as well and I found it so easy.

Answer (score 6):

Default bootstrap navbar icon

`<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>`

Add Font Awesome Icon and Remove `class="navbar-toggler-icon"`

```html
<span>
       <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color:#fff; font-size:28px;"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

One simplest way to encounter this is to use font awesome for example

```html
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
</button>
```

Then u can change the `i` element like you change any other `i`element.

Answer (score 2):

As alternative you always can try a simpler workaround, using another icon, for example:

```
<button type="button" style="background:none;border:none">
    <span class="fa fa-reorder"></span>
</button>
```

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_webapp.asp

```
<button type="button" style="background:none;border:none">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
</button>
```

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/icons/bootstrap_icons_glyphicons.asp

So you gain total control over their color and size:

```
button span {
    /*overwriting*/
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

[image]

(*the button's style applied is just for a quick test*):

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT : my bad! With my answer, the icon won't behave as a toggler**
Actually, it will be shown even when not collapsed...
Still searching...

This would work :

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span>
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </span>
</button>
```

The trick proposed by my answer is to replace the `navbar-toggler` with a classical button class `btn` and then, as answered earlier, use an icon font.

Note, that if you keep `<button class="navbar-toggler">`, the button will have a "strange" shape.

As stated in this [post on github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13156), bootstrap uses some "css trickery", so users don't have to rely on fonts.

So, just don't use the `"navbar-toggler"` class on your button if you want to use an icon font.

Cheers.

Comment: This only "works" if you use Font Awesome which is not part of Bootstrap

Comment: I guess you need to remove the comment on the answer given by Amirreza Mohammadi up the list. Thanks.

Comment: Actually if you remove ```navbar-toggler``` class from button on Bootstrap 4.6 (I do not know the other minor versions of version 4 because I did not try) then it will be visible on desktop view because it is also required for mobile view.

Answer (score 2):

I just developed a considerably easier solution. (Yes, I know this is an old question but someone researching this same issue may find this useful.)

I was using an SVG called hamburger.svg. I looked at it with a text editor and couldn't find anything that was setting a colour for the three lines - I'm guessing it defaults to black because that's certainly the behaviour I get - so I simply added a "stroke" parameter to the definition of the SVG. That didn't QUITE work - the borders of the three lines were my chosen colour (white) but the rest of the line was still black so I added a "fill" parameter as well. And that did the trick!

Here is the code for the original hamburger.svg in its entirety:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><!DOCTYPE svg  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN'  'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'><svg height="32px" id="Layer_1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><path d="M4,10h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2s-0.896-2-2-2H4C2.896,6,2,6.896,2,8S2.896,10,4,10z M28,14H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2  s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2S29.104,14,28,14z M28,22H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2  S29.104,22,28,22z"/></svg>
```

And here is the code for the new SVG after I edited it and saved it as hamburger_white.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><!DOCTYPE svg  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN'  'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'><svg height="32px" id="Layer_1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><path d="M4,10h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2s-0.896-2-2-2H4C2.896,6,2,6.896,2,8S2.896,10,4,10z M28,14H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2  s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2S29.104,14,28,14z M28,22H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2  S29.104,22,28,22z" stroke="white" fill="white"/></svg>
```

As you can see if you scroll way over to the right, all I did was add:

```
stroke="white" fill="white"
```

to the very end of the path. The other thing I had to do was change the file name of the hamburger in the HTML. No messing with the CSS at all and no need to track down another icon.

Easy-peasey! You can imitate this to make your hamburger any colour you like.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change in your SCSS:
`$navbar-dark-color: #abcdef; /* <-- here's your color */` or `$navbar-light-color: #abcdef;` if you're using light.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with sass version of bootstrap in *`_variables.scss`* you can find *`$navbar-inverse-toggler-bg`* or *`$navbar-light-toggler-bg`* where you can change the color and style of your toggle button.

In html you have to use *`navbar-inverse`* or *`navbar-light`* depending on which version you want to use.

Comment: doesn't work in bootstrap 4 in regards to navbar-light

Answer (score 0):

Check the best solution for custom hamburger nav.

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css";
.bg-iconnav {
  background: #f0323d;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0323d 0%, #e6366c 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f0323d 0%, #e6366c 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0323d 0%, #e6366c 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f0323d', endColorstr='#e6366c', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<button class="navbar-toggler bg-iconnav" type="button">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

[demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vQjH.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this
filter: invert(100%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(0deg) brightness(100%) contrast(100%);

Comment: Your answer needs some improvement, check [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer#:~:text=Read%20the%20question%20carefully&text=Your%20answer%20can%20say%20%E2%80%9Cdon,or%20simplifications%20in%20your%20answer.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As of November-2023 for Bootstrap v5.3.2, you need to add the class `"bg-dark"` and `data-bs-theme="dark"` to the `nav` element, as follows:

```html
<nav class="navbar bg-dark" data-bs-theme="dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">[Your brand]</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Bootstrap Documentation: Navbar color schemes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/#color-schemes)