# Why is the css color syntax in my li tag not working

Tags: html, jquery, css, colors, html-lists

I am struggling with changing the color of my font in my nav bar button eg. Home to white. In my style.css file I first used .navbar-nav li but then the padding did not work, when I changed it to .navbar-nav ul the padding then worked. I then had to use .navbar-nav li a for the next style syntax to work and all seem to work except for the color syntax. Please advise what I am doing wrong for the color syntax not to work.

The color syntax again does not work in my .fa-bars class conditions but the font size in that class does work.

The last problem I seem to have is that the syntax in my .promo-title class does not work. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#nav-bar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  /* sticky on the top */
}

.navbar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a517ba, #5f1782);
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav ul {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  /*Not working letters in nav bar not white*/
  font-weight: 600;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
}

.fa-bars {
  color: #fff;
  /*Not working menu bars not white*/
  font-size: 30px;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  outline: none;
}


/*--------------banner section------------*/

#banner {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a517ba, #5f1782);
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 5%;
  /*Extended purple banner down*/
}

.promo-title {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="nav-bar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"> </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>       <!--adds menu bars when shrinking screen or in mobile view-->
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <!--ml-auto moves navbar to the right side-->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </section>

  <!--Banner section-->

  <section id="banner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p class="promo-title">BEST CUSTOM DATABASE COMPANY</p>
          <p>Add sentence here not sure what to say just yet but has to be good</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use

```
a.nav-link{
   color:#fff!important;
}
```

Comment: `!important` should be a last resort. It eliminates the possibility of further overrides.

Comment: Any advice on why the syntax in my .promo-title class in css file is not working?

Comment: @Lizzy can you clarify which part of it doesn't work? If you remove the class from the `<p>` tag you can see that the text falls back to default so your class is definitely doing something, we just need to know what specifically you want it to be doing.

Comment: Hi AStombaugh I want to make the font size big and bold in the paragraph. I'm not sure what I did but when I added an image in the banner in the html file it seemed to fix the problem. Perhaps my banner width was to small

Answer (score 1):

Your selector specificity isn't high enough, so the Bootstrap styles take precedence. A quick look at your browser's document inspector reveals this. Use a more specific selector.

[The same is true for the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68069042/how-an-i-change-the-bootstrap-5-navbar-button-border-and-icon-color) (but you should remove the default Bootstrap icon).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#nav-bar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  /* sticky on the top */
}

.navbar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a517ba, #5f1782);
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.navbar-nav ul {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.navbar.navbar-light .navbar-nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
}

body .navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  outline: none;
}


/*--------------banner section------------*/

#banner {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a517ba, #5f1782);
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 5%;
  /*Extended purple banner down*/
}

.promo-title {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="nav-bar">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"> </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <!--ml-auto moves navbar to the right side-->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">SERVICES</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </section>

  <!--Banner section-->

  <section id="banner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p class="promo-title">BEST CUSTOM DATABASE COMPANY</p>
          <p>Add sentence here not sure what to say just yet but has to be good</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```